# lang option does not work in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, fullcalendar

instead of using a **Full Calendar plugin,** I managed to use the JavaScript and jQuery to display my event data to a calendar (I created my own post type as I do not know how to use WP-Calendar plugin). It works fine and other options works fine except lang option!

As FullCalendar displays it in English, I wanted to configure it to Korean so for example I did it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                lang: 'ko',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev, next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: themeforce.events
            });
    });
```

It worked fine a separate PHP (not the `functions.php` for each theme) but now in WordPress it does not. Does anyone have any idea why this might cause a problem?

Plugin website: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-calendar/

Comment: I did not use that plugin but okay I will add the link for you

Comment: But, is `.fullCallendar({})` native?

Comment: I do not know what do you mean by native function? sorry

Comment: He means: how can you use this function without using the plugin?

Comment: because I have enqueued javascript and relevant files so I do not have to use the plugin to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found [any **`lang`** parameter inside `fullcalendar.js`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-calendar/tags/1.5.3/js/fullcalendar.js#L21). But these options will do what you need:

```
// time formats
titleFormat: {
    month: 'MMMM yyyy',
    week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}",
    day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'
},
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',
    week: 'ddd M/d',
    day: 'dddd M/d'
},
timeFormat: { // for event elements
    '': 'h(:mm)t' // default
},

// locale
isRTL: false,
firstDay: 0,
monthNames: ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
dayNames: ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
dayNamesShort: ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
buttonText: {
    prev: '&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;',
    next: '&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;',
    prevYear: '&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;',
    nextYear: '&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;',
    today: 'today',
    month: 'month',
    week: 'week',
    day: 'day'
},
```

Comment: Actually i was so stupid. I did not even load language package :) that is why it is not working oh my :P

Comment: But, where did you see the option `lang` for the calendar? I searched the code and found nothing...

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/lang/ were you looking for WP Calendar???

Comment: Well, I followed the link on the question and checked the **JavaScript** files, the contents of the `/lang` folder is usually for **PHP** translation only.